# Push Notification based on Firebase update

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I currently have an application that uses IONIC 2 with Firebase.

I have one main collection and was wondering if it would be possible to send a push notification to all users (somehow) when something is added to the Firebase collection.

I'm not sure how I would go about this or even know if this is possible.

Thanks

Comment: Have you taken a look at [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/)?

Answer (score 0):

This is very possible, below are the most helpful tutorials on integrating push notifications with Firebase, in my opinion.

- [Simon Willshire's Tutorial](http://simonwillshire.com/blog/Ionic-2-FCM-Notifications/)
- [Ankush Aggarwal's Tutorial](https://medium.com/@ankushaggarwal/push-notifications-in-ionic-2-658461108c59)

There's a lot of research that you should have been able to do, these links included. Please update this question if you find any errors.